# Model.add() in multiple database configuration

Tags: django, multi-database, django-related-manager

The related manager has [a method called `add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) that, "Adds the specified model objects to the related object set."

For example, you can do:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
e = Entry.objects.get(id=234)
b.entry_set.add(e) # Associates Entry e with Blog b.
```

When you call `add`, it automatically does a save. How do you pass keyword arguments to the save method that it calls? In my case, I want to pass `using='my-other-db', force_insert=True` to the save method, since I am in a multi-database environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: But you can't add an Entry in a different database from the parent Blog anyway, since the foreign keys wouldn't work.